# Using lambdas does not compile when trying to pass in a method expecting a SAM interface

Tags: kotlin, lambda, functional-programming

I am trying to understand lambdas and Kotlin. I created this trivial example

```
interface OnClickListener {
    fun onClick(s: String)
}

class Button {
    var clickListener: OnClickListener? = null

    fun setOnClickListener(listener: OnClickListener?) {
        clickListener = listener
    }
    fun click() {
        clickListener?.onClick("hello")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val b = Button()
    b.setOnClickListener(
        object : OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(s: String) {
                println(s)
            }

        }
    )

   /* 
   Variation 1
   val l = {
        s -> println(s)
    }
    b.clickListener = l*/

    /*
    Variation 2

    b.setOnClickListener{
        s -> println(s)
    }
    */

    /*
    Variation 3

    b.clickListener = {
            s -> println(s)
    }
    */

    b.click()
}
```

So the above code only compiles if I pass an anonymous object. But I wanted to figure out how to use the lambdas.
None of the 3 variation to use a lambda compiles.
I thought since the `OnClickListener` is a SAM I should easily be able to pass in a lambda
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @TaseerAhmad: I get a compilation error for `b.setOnClickListener{s -> println(s)}` that says: `Type mismatch. Required: OnClickListener? Found: (???) -> ???`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to use a lambda, you need to use a Java interface.

First, create a Java file and create an interface:

```
public interface OnClickListener {
   void onClick(String s);
}
```

Then in your `main`:

```
   b.setOnClickListener(OnClickListener { s ->
        println(s)
   })
```

As for your `Button` class:

```
class Button {
 var clickListener: OnClickListener? = null //You can use this too but there's another way as well.

 //lateinit var clickListener: OnClickListener //Telling the compiler that you will initialize it later on.

 fun setOnClickListener(listener: OnClickListener) { //removed redundant ? from the function signature.
     clickListener = listener
 }
  fun click() {
     clickListener?.onClick("hello")  //Incase of lateinit, you don't need a '?' anymore
  }
}
```

SAM conversion only works between a Java code and a Kotlin code.

**EDIT:** Since in Kotlin, you can store a function in a variable as well, here is my another two cents on how you can do it in a different way:

```
class Button {
   lateinit var myFunction: (String) -> Unit

   fun setOnClickListener(block : (String) -> Unit) {
      myFunction = block //storing state of your 'listener'
   }

   fun onClick() = myFunction.invoke("Invoked from onClick function")
}
```

Then in your `main`:

```
fun main() {
   val button = Button()
   button.setOnClickListener { s ->
       println(s)
   }

   button.onClick()
}
```

Comment: And to add: the reason that SAM conversion doesn't work for Kotlin interfaces is that in general, Kotlin methods are expected to accept function types directly — unlike Java, there's no need to create interfaces for them.

Comment: @gidds: So that means that I should have defined that `setOnClickListener` expects a function argument?

Comment: @TaseerAhmad: So I can't use a Kotlin interface? I thought there was no difference with a Java interface

Comment: In Kotlin, functions are the first-class citizen, meaning you can pass them around as function parameters with the help of higher-order functions. A higher-order function can accept a lambda(an anonymous function). You don't need a 'middleman' interface to do that.

Comment: @TaseerAhmad: Somehow I thought that a SAM interface is interchangable with a function variable

Comment: @Jim I added a new way to the approach that does not make use of an explicit interface. All done via lambdas/HOFs.

Answer (score 1):

As Taseer Ahmad points out, SAM conversion only works for Java interfaces since Kotlin already has proper function types. Of course, an easy way around this is to simply define a second `setOnClickListener` method that takes a function type

```
class Button {
    var clickListener: OnClickListener? = null

    fun setOnClickListener(listener: OnClickListener?) {
        clickListener = listener
    }

    inline fun setOnClickListener(crossinline listener: (String) -> Unit) {
        setOnClickListener(object : OnClickListener { 
            override fun onClick(s: String) = listener(s)
        })
    }

    fun click() {
        clickListener?.onClick("hello")
    }
}
```

This then allows you to write `b.setOnClickListener { println(it) }`. I always inline methods like this as a habit, but it's not really required, so you can remove the `inline` and `crossinline` if you want.

Comment: Somehow I thought that a SAM interface is interchangable with a function variable