# Kotlin how to achieve android setOnClickListener like syntax

Tags: android, kotlin, functional-programming

In `Android`+`Kotlin` both of the following syntaxes are valid

`view.setOnClickListener(this)` and `view.setOnClickListener {}` I have been trying to achieve this syntax for my custom functional interface without any success. Here is what I have tried so far

```
interface OnClickListener {
    fun onClick(str: String)
}

class Test {
    fun setClickListener(listener: OnClickListener) {
        listener.onClick("")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val test = Test()
    test.setClickListener { str -> 

    }
}
```

in the above snippet code in `main()` fails to compile as it needs an anonymous object of `OnClickListener` class. How can I achieve the same syntax for client code as with the original `OnClickListener`?

Comment: I recently wrote an answer for this, [take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57921406/9968399).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible if you are using Kotlin only. You can achieve this by using @FunctionalInterface of JAVA. No matter how inconsistent it seems, its by design in language.

> It seems that SAM conversion only works for Java interfaces. According to the forum discussion this is by design: Kotlin has functional types and everyone should just use them. While the argument is perfectly reasonable the restriction does feel a bit inconsistent.

Please check this [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7770)

Answer (score 1):

What I like to do is:

```
inline fun View.onClick(crossinline clickListener: (View) -> Unit) {
    this.setOnClickListener {
        clickListener(this)
    }
}
```

Now you can call

```
button.onClick {
    // handle click
}
```

---

**EDIT:** ah, I misunderstood your question. The answer is

```
interface OnClickListener {
    fun onClick(target: Any)
}

class Test {
    private var onClickListener: OnClickListener? = null

    fun setOnClickListener(listener: OnClickListener?) {
        this.onClickListener = listener
    }

    fun doClick() {
        onClickListener?.onClick(this)
    }
}

inline fun Test.setOnClickListener(crossinline listener: (Test) -> Unit) {
    this.setOnClickListener(object: OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(target: Any) {
            listener.invoke(target as Test)
        }
    })
}

fun main() {
    val test = Test()
    test.setOnClickListener { t -> 
        println("hello")
    }

    test.doClick()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
fun setClickListener(listener: (String) -> Unit)
```

and then call `listener("some string")`

Comment: This way I loose my interface, which I don't want I still want to keep interface. So that my classes can extend from it.