# when observing liveData using kotlin why dont we use the onChanged method

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new in kotlin. In java to observe LiveData we do something like below:

```
    final Observer<String> nameObserver = new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final String newName) {
        // do some work;
        }
    };

model.getCurrentName().observe(this, nameObserver);
```

but in kotlin

```
val nameObserver = Observer<String> { newName ->
    // do some work
    }

model.currentName.observe(this, nameObserver)
```

So, my confusion is where did the override method onChanged go in kotlin? why aren't we writing it?

Also, in java The Observer is initiated with

> new Observer()

but in kotlin its

> Observer

I understand that I don't need to use new keyword. But what about the Parentheses `()` ? why isn't it used in kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you can write `Observer { }` in Kotlin due to SAM(Single abstract method) conversion. If you have one abstract method in a Java `interface`, you can convert it to a lambda expression. This offers more readable code and the `onChanged` method is still there but works under the hood.

> Just like Java 8, Kotlin supports SAM conversions. This means that Kotlin function literals can be automatically converted into implementations of Java interfaces with a single non-default method, as long as the parameter types of the interface method match the parameter types of the Kotlin function.

[SAM conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions)

To create anonymous class, you use `new` keyword, while in Kotlin you use `object:` keyword.

```
object : Observer<T> {

}
```

Comment: thanks. Can you also answer this - [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58583899/how-to-apply-sam-conversion-to-my-anonymous-class-implementation-and-convert-it)

Comment: @RashedulHasan [Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57921406/9968399)